# Template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

We have following class definition

```
template<typename T>
class Klass {...}
```

and we also have below two instantiations

```
Klass<int> i;
Klass<double> d;
```

how many copies of Klass' methods are generated by the C++ compiler?
Can somebody explain it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Klass` isn't a type, so it doesn't make sense to talk of `Klass`'s methods. `Kalss<int>` is a type with it's own methods, and so is `Klass<double>`. In your example there would be one set of methods for each type.

**Edit** in real life, it isn't as simple as that. The question of the actual existence of the methods also depends on other factors, see @KerrekSB's answer to this question.

Comment: I think some linkers *can* optimize away the duplicated members, but it's certainly not guaranteed.

Comment: @StephenNewell I am sure that works for template specializations of the same type across translation units, but do you mean it could work for methods that don't depend on the template parameters? I don't understand how the lookup could work for that.

Comment: @juanchpanza: The explanation I was given (this was from a coworker several years ago) was that the compiler can export information about the implementation in the object files so the linker can work it's magic.  It can obviously only work for things like the `size()` member of a data structure and it's possible he may have been mentioning some future optimizations some vendor was bragging about.

Comment: @StephenNewell damn, now I am going to have to figure out if my compiler of choice actually does that!

Comment: One interesting thing is that any inlined template function can effectively be collapsed across all types anyway.  Since templates can effectively be totally inlined since the implementations are available during each compilation unit, the optimizer will be able to make all sorts of decisions that are well outside my pay grade :).

Answer (score 6):

Each template instance is an entirely separate, distinct and independent type of its own. However, the code for class template member functions is only generated if the member function is actually *used* for a given template instantiation (unless you instantiate the template *explicitly* for some set of parameters). Among other things, this means that if some class template member function's *body* doesn't actually make sense for a given template parameter, then you can still use the overall template as long as you don't invoke that member function, since the code for the member function will never get compiled.

Also bear in mind that templates can be specialized:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {
    int bar;
    void chi();
};

template <> struct Foo<int> {
    double bar(bool, char) const;
    typedef std::vector<bool> chi;
    bool y;
};
```

As you can see, there's a lot you cannot just tell from a template itself until you see which actual instantiations you'll be talking about.